# Ramification theory, What is the relation between $K_S$ and $L_S$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ramification

Let $L/K$ be a finite extension of number field.

Let $S$ be a set of places of $K$ containing Archimedean places.
Let write $K_S$ for the largest subfield of $\overline{K}$ containing $K$ that is ramified only at primes in $S$. Let $S'$ be set of places of $L$ above $S$.

I think $K_S \subset L_{S'}$, but can we say the other inclusion $L_{S'} \subset K_{S}$in the case $L\subset K_S$?